# MongoDB: Aggregate Documents per Calender Week and Year and calculate the total amount of all Values of one field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

```
{
    "GU" : "Person2",
    "CW" : 2,
    "Year" : 2015,
    "_id" : "01"
},
{
    "GU" : "Person2",
    "CW" : 2,
    "Year" : 2015,
    "_id" : "02"
},
{
    "GU" : "Person1",
    "CW" : 2,
    "Year" : 2015,
    "_id" : "03"
},
{
    "GU" : "Person1",
    "CW" : 3,
    "Year" : 2015,
    "_id" : "04"
},
{
    "GU" : "Person1",
    "CW" : 51,
    "Year" : 2014,
    "_id" : "05"
},
{
    "GU" : "Person1",
    "CW" : 51,
    "Year" : 2014,
    "_id" : "06"
}
```

Is there a way to aggregate my Data so it will be grouped per CW and Year and I will get the count of the different Persons per week?

So in the end my data should look like this:

```
{Year: 2014, CW:51, GU:{Person1:2}},
{Year: 2015, CW:2, GU:{Person1:1, Person2:2}},
{Year: 2015, CW:3, GU:{Person1:1}}
```

Comment: Are the documents already published to the client, or are you trying to do this on the server?

Comment: The aggregation is done on the server .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve that by grouping two consecutive times:

```
db.mycol.aggregate([
    {$group:{
        _id: {Year: "$Year", CW:"$CW", GU: "$GU"},
        total:{  
            $sum:1
        }
    }},
    {$group:{
        _id: {Year: "$_id.Year", CW:"$_id.CW"},
        GUs: { $push:  { GU: "$_id.GU", total: "$total" } }
    }},
    {$sort: {"_id.Year" : 1, "_id.CW" : 1}}
])
```

**Edit**: added the sort to the aggregation pipeline

And the results will be:

```
{
    "result" : [
            {
                    "_id" : {
                            "Year" : 2014,
                            "CW" : 51
                    },
                    "GUs" : [
                            {
                                    "GU" : "Person1",
                                    "total" : 2
                            }
                    ]
            },
            {
                    "_id" : {
                            "Year" : 2015,
                            "CW" : 2
                    },
                    "GUs" : [
                            {
                                    "GU" : "Person1",
                                    "total" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                    "GU" : "Person2",
                                    "total" : 2
                            }
                    ]
            },
            {
                    "_id" : {
                            "Year" : 2015,
                            "CW" : 3
                    },
                    "GUs" : [
                            {
                                    "GU" : "Person1",
                                    "total" : 1
                            }
                    ]
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was exactly what I was looking for. I already tried the second grouping, but I didn't know that I can "use" the first grouped items in the second group via push. That explains / helps a lot